# Why can certain variables be left out of an Objective function in Mathematical Programming?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, programming

I have an objective function that has the form:

\begin{equation}
 \min \qquad \sum_{i} \omega_{i}x_{i}q_{i}
\end{equation}

Where $\omega_{i}$ is the weight of variable $i$, $x$ is the decision variable which represents a value between 0 and 1. Finally, $q_{i}$ is the maximum available quantity of item $i$ . There are constraints to the problem, however I won't include them here as I don't think they are necessary. When I solved this problem using a solver in JULIA I found that the result was the same whether or not $q$ was included in the objective function and was wondering how I could interpret it. I can provide further context to the problem if required.

Comment: Hold up, is each $x_i$ and $w_i$ a vector?

Comment: No they are elements within a vector $x$ and $\omega$

Comment: Then why do you write $w_i^Tx_i$? Also, are the $q_i$'s positive?

Comment: Apologies that's a typo on my part and yes the q's are positive. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming q is given, try solving Max obj = $x+y$ and obj2 = $3x+ 5y$ where $0 \le x,y \le 9$: All arbitrary.
Other than the optimal value, the solution will be the same. Reason is coefficients (here q) impact the objective value but feasible region/convex hull remains unchanged if constraints are the same.

Comment: Thanks I'll think about this a bit more but I feel I understand it a little better now.